# Text-Decoration: underline has undocumented line thickness property

Tags: html, css

I wanted to control the line thickness of the underline property in my css file. I simply tried out something like this...

```
h1{
  text-decoration: underline black 1px; 
}
```

... and it worked!

[image]

However, when I tried to validate my CSS file, the W3C CSS validator indicates that the '1px' property isn't a valid text-decoration value. I also cannot find line thickness to be a part of [text-decoration's properties](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-decoration.asp). Yet, I find that it works on Chrome, Firefox and Edge.

Can anybody explain why a CSS property that isn't documented and doesn't validate nevertheless works?

Comment: the property is called `text-decoration-thickness` - [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-thickness)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thickness can be controlled with: `text-decoration-thickness` property.
The color of the with: `text-decoration-color` property.

```css
h1 {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-thickness: 50px;
  text-decoration-color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Our Elixirs</h1>
```

Modern browsers have really good UA (User Agents = default CSS) to correct most markup error. However the best place to look for documentation is [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-line)

Answer (score 1):

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration) lists it.

If you want to be on the safer side, you can define [text-decoration-thickness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-thickness) separately.

> Can anybody explain why a CSS property that isn't documented and doesn't validate nevertheless works?

That's modern web dev for you.